# Dynamically change view constraint when related view is dragged

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, nslayoutconstraint

I have two views that overlay each other. When i drag `viewA` upward, `viewB` becomes visible. When `viewA`is dragged all the way to the top, these two views are lined up perfectly so that `viewA.bottom == viewB.top`. This is accomplished by using autolayout/constraints and works really nice on 4" screen, but the alignment breaks for 4,7" and 5,5" screens.

I need to adjust the height or the top-space-constraint on `viewB` at runtime so it matches the `viewA.bottom` value.

So far I've been playing around with KVO for listening on `viewB.frame` changes (smelly) and manipulated the scrollview frame directly, but without luck. The following code snippet is the most promising, but I can't make it to work in "realtime". `recognizer.view` is the infoCenterView.

```
UIView *infoCenterView;          // viewA
UIScrollView *scrollView;  // viewB
UITableView *tableView;    // child of viewB
NSLayoutConstraint *scrollViewTopSpaceConstraint;

- (IBAction)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    CGPoint center = recognizer.view.center;
    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];

    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];
        center.y += translation.y;

        // Don't allow translation outside screen frame
        if (center.y < self.yMin || center.y > self.yMax)
            return;

        recognizer.view.center = center;  // (1)
        self.scrollViewTopSpaceConstraint.constant += translation.y;  // (2)
    }

    else if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

        if (center.y > self.yMin && center.y < ((self.yMax + self.yMin) / 2)) {
            center.y = self.yMin;  // Move to top
        }
        else if (center.y >= ((self.yMax + self.yMin) / 2) && center.y < self.yMax) {
            center.y = self.yMax;  // Move to bottom
        }

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                              delay:0
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
                         animations:^{
                             recognizer.view.center = center;
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             // (3)
                             self.scrollViewTopSpaceConstraint.constant = 200;
                         }];
}
```

// (1) and (2)

If both of these lines is executed, only the tableView height is adjusted in "realtime" and infoCenterView will not move. However, if (2) is commented out, infoCenterView can be moved.

// (3)

If (2) is commented out and (3) is executed, and if infoCenterView is dragged to the top of the screen, it will unintentionally drop to the bottom and tableView height is properly set.

What is going on here? Ideas are very welcome!

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the constraint value in then containing view's "viewDidLayoutSubview" method?

Comment: Only `viewWillLayoutSubviews`is called a couple of times at start up, but not when viewA is dragged. Can't find any good reasons why it's not working for `handlePan:` UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged

Comment: Done some more testing, got some strange results.